# Is it possible to override the ASP.NET project references?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference, web-config, shared-libraries

is it possible to override the references in the Project references with new versions without requiring to compile the projects?

For example, we have shared libraries:

```
MainProject.Shared
- Shared.Security v1.0.0
- Shared.Module v1.0.0
- etc.
```

And applications are referencing those libraries:

```
ProjectOne
- References
  - Shared.Security v1.0.0
  - Shared Module v1.0.0

ProjectTwo
- References
  - Shared.Security v1.0.0
  - Shared Module v1.0.0

. . .
```

We have new versions (V2.0.0) of Shared.Security, Shared.Module, etc.

Is there any way to override the v1.0.0 references with v2.0.0 somehow WITHOUT requiring all the projects to be recompiled?

Will adding the following in web.config take priority over the project references?

```
<add assembly="MainProject.Shared.Security, v2.0.0" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a [binding redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions).

Comment: That looks promising, Kenneth K!  Thanks, I will look into the link further to see if that will work in our scenarios.